# How to use an instance variable of one object on another object java

Tags: java, object

I am making a simple game.
When I call the fight method the damage received by the character when it is hit is its own damage variable
For example 
Knight- 
Health: 100
Damage: 20

Soldier-
health: 100
Damage: 10

when I call my method an the knight attacks the soldier and the soldier attacks the knight their health is as follows

Knight-> 80 Health
Soldier-> 90 Health

when it should be the other way round

example code

```
public abstract class BasicCharacter 
{
private double health;
private double damage;
private double attackProbability;
private String name;


public BasicCharacter(double hp,double attp,double d, String n)
{   
    health=hp;
    attackProbability=attp;
    damage=d;
    name=n; 


}


public void setHealth(double hp)
{  
    health=hp;
}

public double getHealth()
{
    return health;
}



public double getDamage()
{
    return damage;
}




public void fight()
{


    double prob=Math.random();

    if(prob<attackProbability)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name+" attacked for " + damage+    "\n" + name + " health " + health +" left");
        health=health-damage;
    }
    else {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + " missed");
    }


}
}
```

both the soldiers and the knight are subclasses of BasicCharacter

```
  public class soldier extends BasicCharacter{}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because in your `fight()` method, you are deducting the health from the object's own damage:

```
health=health-damage;
```

What you actually wants is probably:

```
fight(BasicCharacter target){
    target.setHealth(target.getHealth() - this.damage);
}
```

You can add an argument to your fight method which indicates the fighting target.

Comment: would this be in the same method or a separate method as all characters are part of this class

Comment: @thebigone You can implement this in the abstract class for BasicCharacter. So whoever extends BasicCharacter will have this defaut implementation. You may still choose to override this method in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
Knight attacking Soldier

A simple method that will handle the damaging, send in object you want to damage and the amount of damage.

```
public void damaging(Object object, Double damage){
 if(object instanceof Soldier){
 ((Soldier)object).setHealth(((Soldier)object).getHealth()-damage);
 }
}
```

Comment: Why should someone use `Object`? You don't even want an `Object` here, since this method can only work with `Soldier`. So how about using either `Soldier` or better `BasicCharacter` instead?